# Portable Windows 10 with normal installation

Tags: windows-10, ssd, license, portable

I've an original Windows 10 Pro installed on SSD.

I've 2 hd caddy that allows me to move my SSD between my Home Computer and my Laptop.

It works fine except for 1 thing: the license. When i move my SSD my license is deactivated.

Is there any solution to allow me this kind of portability ? ( I would avoid any kind of USB solution )

Comment: "When i move my SSD my license is deactivated." - You need a seperate license for your home computer.  If you already have 2 licenses you might avoid this problem if you link your licenses to your Microsoft Account.

Comment: So can i've 2 license on a single installation?

Comment: If you connect your license to your account, the license for the machine, would be handled digitally.  You still need 2 seperate individual licenses though.

Comment: You should be using [Windows To Go](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/windows/plan/windows-to-go-overview). Your situation is exactly what it is designed for,

Comment: Just an FYI, this isn't the best of ideas and will result in system instability at some point due to the CPU, and other, drivers.  Recommended way to do this is to have three partitions, two for Windows and one for user data.  You can `SysPrep` the Home PC's install by capturing a WIM of the Home PC first, use `SysPrep` on the Home PC, capture a WIM of the result, apply that WIM to the 2nd Windows partition, then format & apply the first captured WIM to the first Windows partition.  Each OS on the two partitions would then be configured to use the third partition for user data (Location tab).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you can achieve so because whenever a windows is activated for the first time the following hardware specification is sent to Microsoft:

> Display Adapter
>   SCSI Adapter
>   IDE Adapter
>   Network Adapter MAC Address
>   RAM Amount Range
>   Processor Type
>   Processor Serial Number
>   Hard Drive Device
>   Hard Drive Volume Serial Number (VSN)
>   CDROM / CDRW / DVDROM

And when the same Product Key is installed in another system then windows matches all the above specification stored in their server with the current hardware specification which will obviously does not match.
However, whenever you will upgrade/ change your three or more hardware you will need to call Microsoft to re-activate your copy of windows, after verifying it is you they will they will update your new hardware specification in their server and your copy of window will be re-activated.

Want to know more about [Microsoft Product Activation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457054.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution myself. I have 2 licences for 2 laptops and they activating each change. But i have a further method. I have installed evolution copy of Windows enterprise which I can use for 90 days .It works. Its easiliy can extend another 90 days by rearm command.